How to calculate circular bit difference?
Given two systems with same fixed-bit, e.g. two 8-bits, A and B.
How to calculate circular difference?
Example, both are using unsigned integer format:
A: 250
B: 1
If we perform substraction, resulting 249 difference step, but if we are considering on overflow perspective, resulting 7 difference step. (251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 0, 1). Back to zero due to overflow.
